# Move from MySQL to AWS DynamoDB? 5m rows, 4 tables, 1k writes p/s

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, solr, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-rds

Considering moving my MySQL architecture to AWS DynamoDB. My application has a requirement of 1,000 r/w requests per second. How does this play with PHP/updates? Having 1,000 workers process DynamoDB r/w's seems like it will have a higher toll on CPU/Memory than MySQL r/w's.

I have thought about a log file to store the updated information, then create scripts to process the log files to remove db load - however stunted by file locking, would be curious if anyone had any ideas on implementing this - 300 separate script's would be writing to a single log file. The log file could then be processed every minute to the db. Not sure how this could be implemented without locking. Server script is written in PHP.

Current Setup
MYSQL Database (RDS on AWS)

- table A has 5m records- the main db table, 30 columns mostly numerical + text <500 chars. (Growth +30k records per day). Has relationships with 4 other tables containing;
- table b - 15m records (Growth +90k records per day).
- table c - 2m records (Growth +10k records per day).
- table d - 4m records (Growth +15k records per day).
- table c - 1m records (Growth +5k records per day).

Table A updates around 1,000 records per second then updated / added rows are queued for adding to SOLR search.

Would appreciate some much needed advice to lower costs. Are there hidden costs or other solutions I should be aware of before starting development?

Comment: With DynamoDB you pay for provisioned reads, provisioned writes, and storage.  That is it, no hidden costs. AWS is very transparent with the pricing.

Comment: @JaredHatfield Thank you. Would you suggest against a log file for this use case and to keep on exploring DynamoDB? Is it as fast as MySQL when dealing with this level of record updates per second? Batch updates are not an option. Concern comes from reading many conflicting stories online.

Comment: @JaredHatfield Currently operating on 750 i/o per second.  Feel like dynamoDB couldn't handle this level of w/r's.

Comment: DynamoDB are NoSQL. It WILL lag behind well design RDBMS like MySQL under the same hardware. NoSQL are suppose to use for analytical purpose ONLY, it is no mean for  continuous transaciton update. NoSQL vendors try to make more sales by overhype it to replace RDBMS. Both has its own niche, you just need to be careful.

Comment: Unless you intended to create prototype of non-uniform tables, then dynamoDB, otherwise, stick to RDBMS.  Or perhaps use a  NoSQL wrapper on top of the RDBMS. But bare in mind, developer that "prefer" NoSQL may means they may have a poor understanding of data structure, and the technical debt might accumulate.

Comment: Have you looked at Aurora?  You mention MySQL and RDS but not Aurora, so I assume you are not using it now.  It is supposed to be faster than MySQL for given hardware,  which should mean more work for less cost, and it is -- fundamentally -- still MySQL.  I have worked with it and found no unpleasant surprises or unexpected incompatibility, but haven't benchmarked it against other MySQL configurations.  @mootmoot is right, the differences between RDBMS and NoSQL are significant and NoSQL is not always a suitable alternative.  There is of course no harm in running a test against DynamoDB.

Comment: @mootmoot thank you for the insight. I hadn't realised this, perhaps NoSQL is the wrong place to be looking in that case. The sales hype has certainly pushed me into investigating.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks for mentioning Aurora, yes I had considered this, but recently read a benchmark that showed no great advantages. Also the main cost is being lost via I/O requests. RDS is charging me $0.10 per 1 million I/O requests. Aurora is apparently $0.20 per million.

Comment: RDS is kinda tricky. I did see some admin pre-allocate tons of disk space using GB x 3 Iops  method. Aurora is not viable if you use trigger and stored procedure. Sometime complicate data workflow just cannot be done easily without those.

Answer (score 1):

I afraid the scope for performance improvement for your DB just too broad.

- IOPS. Some devops choose provision 200GB storage (200 x 3 = 600 IOPS)
  than the "provisioned IOPS" for smaller storage (say they only need
  50GB then purchase provisioned IOS). You need to launch an excel
  sheet to find the pricing/performance sweet spot.
- You might need to create another "denormalised table" from table A,
  if frequent select from table A but not traverse the whole
  `text <500 chars`. Don't underestimated the text workload.
- Index, index , index.
- if you deal with tons of non-linear search, perhaps copy part of relevant data to dynamodb that you think will improve the performance, test it first, but maintain the RDBMS structure.
- there is no one size fit all solutions.  Please also inspect usage of Message queue if required.

Adding 200k records/days actually not much for today RDBMS. Even 1000 IOPS are only happen in burst.  If query is the heaviest part, then you need to optimize that part.